# Use Nginx and/or Traefik for serving ML models

Tags: nginx, machine-learning, traefik, tensorflow-serving, fastapi

I have python based ML model that I want to serve. Based on my research two the most popular options are the following:

```
I. Flask + uWSGI
II. FastAPI + Uvicorn with Gunicorn
```

On top of that we can put Nginx as a reverse proxy (load balancing, caching, security, etc.):

```
I. Flask + uWSGI + Nginx 
II. FastAPI + Uvicorn/Gunicorn + Nginx
```

My questions:

1. Do I need to use Traefik on top of that? Or do I need to change
   Nginx with Traefik?
2. If I have an application which only accepts POST requests do I
   need to still use Nginx and/or Traefik on top of Flask + uWSGI (or
   FastAPI + Uvicorn/Gunicorn)?
3. If I will use Tensorflow Serving or other ML serving solutions
   (Kubeflow, MLflow, Seldon, etc.) is it still recommended to wrap up
   Tensorflow Serving into FastAPI + Uvicorn/Gunicorn + Nginx or/and
   Traefik?

P.S. I am planning conterize applications with Docker and use Swarm or Kubernetes in production.

Comment: 1: Traefik will have the same role as Nginx based on what you've described here

-- 2 & 3: It will mostly on your deployment constraints and needs - which environment, is it only an API ? Do you have static files to serve? but IMO you don't need Nginx/Traefik

Comment: @Julian I have one app that has only APIs and another one API + static files to serve

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do I need to use Traefik on top of that? Or do I need to change Nginx with Traefik?

Based on the fact that you want to deploy multiple Docker containers using Swarm/Kubernetes. I would advise you to use a reverse proxy like Traefik or Nginx.
In my opinion, Traefik is easier to learn and configure. Traefik can also use the Docker socket to detect new launched containers.

Here is an article on how to set up a swarm mode for traefik: [link](https://tiangolo.medium.com/docker-swarm-mode-and-distributed-traefik-proxy-with-https-6df45d0c0fc0)

> 2. If I have an application which only accepts POST requests do I need to still use Nginx and/or Traefik on top of Flask + uWSGI (or FastAPI + Uvicorn/Gunicorn)?
> 3. If I will use Tensorflow Serving or other ML serving solutions (Kubeflow, MLflow, Seldon, etc.) is it still recommended to wrap up
>    Tensorflow Serving into FastAPI + Uvicorn/Gunicorn + Nginx or/and
>    Traefik?

As [Julian](http://Based%20on%20the%20fact%20that%20you%20want%20to%20deploy%20multiple%20Docker%20containers%20using%20Swarm/Kubernetes.%20I%20would%20advise%20you%20to%20use%20a%20reverse%20proxy%20like%20Traefik%20or%20Nginx.%20%20In%20my%20opinion,%20Traefik%20is%20easier%20to%20learn%20and%20configure.%20Traefik%20can%20use%20the%20Docker%20socket%20to%20detect%20new%20launched%20containers.) already mentioned in his comment, it mostly depends on your deployment constraints and needs. FastAPI itself has a great ready-to-go repository with [Docker + FastAPI + Uvicorn/Gunicorn](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker).